# Stash cache site navigation from nav:ee

Tags: stash, cache, navee

So building on the answers from [my previous question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17178/stash-saving-on-get-and-set-performance-benefits), I'm trying to cache the main navigation on my site.

As I understand it, the principle is to cache everything in one big chunk and then use the `stash:nocache` tag to except the conditionals used for the active state.

The relevant part of my code is:

```
{exp:stash:set name="full_nav_cache" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" output="yes" save="yes" refresh="180" replace="no" scope="site"}
    {exp:navee:custom nav_title="main-nav" wrap_type="none"}
        <li class="{stash:nocache}{if '{site_url}{segment_1}/' == {/stash:nocache}'{link}'{stash:nocache}}selected{/if}{/stash:nocache}">
    {/exp:navee:custom}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

However, it seems like the `{segment_1}` variable is still parsed when the cache is saved. In the database I'm seeing:

```
<li class="{if '{site_url}/products/' == 'http://mysite.com/products/'}selected{/if}">
```

But I was expecting:

```
<li class="{if '{site_url}{segment_1}/' == 'http://mysite.com/products/'}selected{/if}">
```

which would then get parsed on the page load. Is the the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use that code in an EE template (rather than a Stash embed) then EE will parse `{segment_1}` early, before tags are run and before Stash can escape it.

See step 1 here: http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf

The good news is you can access any global variable or snippet as a tag like this:

```
{exp:stash:get name="segment_1" type="snippet"}
```

Thus:

```
{exp:stash:set name="full_nav_cache" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" output="yes" save="yes" refresh="180" replace="no" scope="site"}
    {exp:navee:custom nav_title="main-nav" wrap_type="none"}
        <li class="{stash:nocache}{if '{site_url}{exp:stash:get name="segment_1" type="snippet"}/' == {/stash:nocache}'{link}'{stash:nocache}}selected{/if}{/stash:nocache}">
    {/exp:navee:custom}
{/exp:stash:set}
```